# Как передать элемент класса(который является массивом другого класса) в функцию

Tags: java, классы

Делая своё домашнее задание по java, у меня возникла проблема что я не знаю как передать массив собственного класса в функцию (возможно я не правильно выразил проблему, просто в java я новичок). Я попробую донести суть проблемы по коду.

> Задание. Создать базу данных, содержащую результаты экзаменационной сессии студентов курса. Каждая запись хранит: фамилию, инициалы студента; номер зачётки; наименование факультета; курс; результаты сессии для каждого студента; (представляет массив структур из 5 элементов; структура включает: название предмета; фамилию преподавателя; оценку;)

В качестве массива для хранения всех этих данных нужно использовать List/ArrayList.

Код программы:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main_test {
    public static ExamResults exRes = new ExamResults();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        exRes.add(new ExamResult("Ivanov", "Ivan", "Ivanovich", 1, "IKS", 2));

        System.out.println(exRes);
    }
}
```

Класс в котором содержатся все составляющие:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ExamResult {
    String f;
    String i;
    String o;
    int numberGradeBook;
    String facultyName;
    int course;
    Mark[] result = new Mark[5];

    public ExamResult(String f, String i, String o, int numberGradeBook, String facultyName, int course){
        this.setF(f);
        this.setI(i);
        this.setO(o);
        this.setNumberGradeBook(numberGradeBook);
        this.setFacultyName(facultyName);
        this.setCourse(course);
    }

    public String getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public void setF(String f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public String getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(String i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String getO() {
        return o;
    }

    public void setO(String o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    public int getNumberGradeBook() {
        return numberGradeBook;
    }

    public void setNumberGradeBook(int numberGradeBook) {
        this.numberGradeBook = numberGradeBook;
    }

    public String getFacultyName() {
        return facultyName;
    }

    public void setFacultyName(String facultyName) {
        this.facultyName = facultyName;
    }

    public int getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(int course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public Mark[] getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Mark[] result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExamResult{" +
                "f='" + f + '\'' +
                ", i='" + i + '\'' +
                ", o='" + o + '\'' +
                ", numberGradeBook=" + numberGradeBook +
                ", facultyName='" + facultyName + '\'' +
                ", course=" + course +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Класс Mark (описывает последний пункт задания, то есть результат сессии):

```
public class Mark {
    String subjectName;
    String teacherName;
    int mark;

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public String getTeacherName() {
        return teacherName;
    }

    public void setTeacherName(String teacherName) {
        this.teacherName = teacherName;
    }

    public int getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(int mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mark{" +
                "subjectName='" + subjectName + '\'' +
                ", teacherName='" + teacherName + '\'' +
                ", mark=" + mark +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Ну и отдельный класс для массива ArrayList(В нем будут функции для работы с массивом):

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExamResults {

    ArrayList<ExamResult> examResults;

    public ExamResults() {
        this.examResults = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void add(ExamResult examRes) {
        examResults.add(examRes);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExamResults{" +
                "examResults=" + examResults +
                '}';
    }
}
```

В классе ExamResult у меня есть функция для того что бы я мог в main заполнять массив.

```
public ExamResult(String f, String i, String o, int numberGradeBook, String facultyName, int course){
        this.setF(f);
        this.setI(i);
        this.setO(o);
        this.setNumberGradeBook(numberGradeBook);
        this.setFacultyName(facultyName);
        this.setCourse(course);
    }
```

Так вот, проблема тут в том что основные элементы класса я передал, а как мне передать последний массив Mark размерностью 5 (Потому что для каждого студента должно быть 5 оценок по разным предметам). Я хочу добиться того что бы в main через функцию add я мог добавить ещё 5 результатов по сессии.

Возможно где-то плохо сформулировал мысль, прошу прощения, недостаточно ещё знаний что бы рассказать это "правильно".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Делая своё домашнее задание по java, у меня возникла проблема

*"Подъезжая к сией станции ... у меня слетела шляпа." Чехов*

---

```
public ExamResult(String f, String i, String o, 
    int numberGradeBook, String facultyName, int course, 
    Mark m1, Mark m2, Mark m3, Mark m4, Mark m5) {

    this.setF(f);
    this.setI(i);
    this.setO(o);
    this.setNumberGradeBook(numberGradeBook);
    this.setFacultyName(facultyName);
    this.setCourse(course);

    result[0] = m1;
    result[1] = m2;
    result[2] = m3;
    result[3] = m4;
    result[4] = m5;
}


exRes.add(new ExamResult("Ivanov", "Ivan", "Ivanovich", 1, "IKS", 2,
  new Mark("Chemistry", "Mendeleev", 2), ...));
```